# Permissions error SSRS 2016

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I just installed `SQL Server 2016 RC2`, I ran the reporting services setup, everything worked successfully.
Yet when i go into the url it tells me `"The permissions granted to user 'abc\xyz' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)"` I am the only user on the PC.

Comment: Run IE/Chrome etc as admin then grant abc\xyz role membership/perms.